# TCP reset attack / forged TCP reset prevention

Tags: network, attacks, attack-prevention, tcp, iptables

How do you prevent someone from doing an TCP reset attack between client and host without having acess to host?

I am trying to solve a CTF for fun and learning purposes. 
In one of the challenges I establish a connection with a server that starts sending me TCP packages, but I am interupted by a third party that sends what appears to be a  forged tcp reset. I receive a RST, ACK and the packages stops coming.

I have tried both DROPing and REJECTing the RST package without success, using the following command:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -j DROP
```

Is there any way that I could nullify the attacker trying to prevent communication between me and the host?
[image: Wireshark capture]

Comment: Would it be possible to include a packet capture excerpt from tcpdump?

Comment: I screenshoted the packet capture from wireshark: https://imgur.com/a/O67cDG5
Does this help? The packages stops coming after the last RST,ACK package

Comment: Is your client using a static source port? Would changing the source port help? How the the attacker predicting the sequence number to craft the packet with the right headers?

Comment: Are you sure it's from a 3rd party (i.e. is it part of the scenario?)? If so, I would expect some packets from the legitimate server after the RST, since the server probably doesn't know the connection is closed on your end (unless the 3rd party also killed the server's end of the connection).

Comment: The exercise explains that there is a server handing out a free flag, but there is a 3rd party that disrupts the communication. I believe that the scenario is that the 3rd party closes forges RST packages to me and the server and therefore we both close the connection. DROPing or REJECTing the RST doesn't get me any further either.

Comment: @hax I was told within the exercise to use port 1337. I have tried using a range of port numbers and specific port numbers that isn't 1337, but without luck. The server refuses connection without sending any tcp packages. 
Is there some logic that should be applied when guessing port numbers?